# jquery don't submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hi I'm trying to validate form with jquery before submit. The validation works fine, but never submit.

There is the form:

```
<form class="form-signin panel-body" role="form" action="addUser" method="post" id="register">
                    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up</h2>

                    <div id="na" class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                    </div>

                    <div id="su" class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname" required>
                    </div>

                    <div id="user" class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" value="<%= request.getParameter("username1") %>" placeholder="Username" required>
                    </div>

                    <div id="mail" class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control warning" value="<%= request.getParameter("email1") %>" placeholder="Email address" required>
                    </div>

                    <div id="pa" class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<%= request.getParameter("password1") %>" placeholder="Password" required> 
                    </div>

                        <select class="form-control" id="year" name="year">
                            <option value="">Year</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="form-control" id="month" name="month">
                            <option value="">Month</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="form-control" id="day" name="day">
                            <option value="">Day</option>
                        </select>


                    <div class="row">
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                    <label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="sex" name="sex">
                            <option value="Male">Male</option>
                            <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        By clicking Sign up, you are agree to our<a data-toggle="modal" href="#terms"> Terms and
                        Conditions</a> and have read our usage policy data, including ouruse of 
                        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#cookies">cookies</a>. 

                    </label>
                    <button id="send" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" >Sign in</button>
                </form>
```

Mainly I want refuse duplicate username's or email adress. There's my jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#register").submit(function(event){
    //  $("#register").click(function(){    
            var $username = $("#username").val();
            var $mail = $("#email").val();

        // Evita que si alguna comprovacio retorna false s'envi el formulari
        event.preventDefault();

        // Funcio que valida que el nom no estigui en blanc
        if($("#name").val().trim() == ""){
            $("#na").addClass( "has-error");
            return false;
        }

        // Funcio que valida que el cognom no estigui en blanc
        if($("#surname").val().trim() == ""){
            $("#su").addClass( "has-error");
            return false;
        }

        // Funcio ajax per validar que el nom d'usuari no està en ús
        $.ajax({
            url: "/projCreditV1/rwsc/as/check-value/user_name/" + $username,
            success: function(data){
                // Si retorna TRUE vol dir que el nom d'usuari es valid perque no està en ús
                if(data == "true"){
                    $("#mail").removeClass("has-error");
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    $("#user").addClass("has-error");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        // Funcio ajax per validar que el mail no està en ús
        $.ajax({
            url: "/projCreditV1/rwsc/as/check-value/mail/" + $mail,
            success: function(data){
                // Si retorna TRUE vol dir que el mail es valid perque no està en ús
                if(data == "true"){
                    $("#mail").removeClass("has-error");
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    $("#mail").addClass("has-error");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        // Funcio que valida que la contrasenya no estigui en blanc
        if($("#password").val().trim() == ""){
            $("#pa").addClass( "has-error");
            return false;
        }

        });

    });
```

When some field doesn't meets the requirements return false. I think if whole form doesn't return false, should submit..

Thanks

Comment: You could get your answer easily if you some search on SO before asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

please remove the  `event.preventDefault();`.

if you use that code, it will never execute the form.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the submit doesn't finish is the:
event.preventDefault(); line. The return doesn't work  for the async request. Because it doesn't return the value back to the event.

A way to fix this would be:

1. Make a normal button instead of a submit button
2. make jquery do the
   submit.